# When trying to access my sharepoint site in server explorer

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

When trying to access my sharepoint site in server explorer (Sharepoint connection) i get the following problem....
I am running SP 2013 and VS2012

[image: My Problem]